# Laravel: how to process queue using Amazon SQS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-4

I am using the code below to queue emails using Amazon SQS, the message do queue up in the Amazon SQS queue but I don't know how to process it so that the emails are delivered to their recipient. I am using a shared server for my project where I have no access to SSH.

```
//User Registration Email
static function UserRegEmail($LastName,$FirstName,$Email){

    $user = array('LastName' => $LastName,
                'FirstName' => $FirstName,
                'Email' => $Email);

     $data = array(
        'LastName' => $LastName, 
        'FirstName'=> $FirstName,
        'senderName' => 'MyCompanyName', 
        'Email' => $Email
    );

        Mail::queue('emails.user_welcome', $data, function($message) use ($user)
        {
            $message->from( 'no-reply@domain.com', 'MyCompanyName' );
            $message->to($user['Email'], $user['LastName'].' '.$user['FirstName'])->subject('Welcome!');
        });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure queues first to be able to use `Mail::queue`. There's a [chapter in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues) that explains it pretty well.
I've no experience with Amazon SQS, but Laravel theoretically supports it.

Head over to **/app/config/queue.php** and change the config

```
'default' => 'sqs'
```

And fill in your details for `connections > sqs`

After that, everything should just work :)

Comment: The configuration has being done, and jobs are queuing successfully. I just want to know how to fire the jobs..

Comment: Ups I'm sorry, should have read slower... Are you able to set up cronjobs?

Comment: I know how to, is it needed?

Comment: I don't know if it really is needed, but to "run" the queue there's the artisan command `queue:work`. So you could have a cronjob that runs `php artisan queue:work` every 5 minutes or so

Comment: Don't have access to SSH cause I am on a shared sever, can't do `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: Yes but you can create a cronjob that does that, don't you?

Comment: I used `IronMQ` instead